# How to remove last occurrence of a character in a string in Apex?

Tags: replace, salesforce, apex, salesforce-lightning

I have a string as below.

```
  *Two professional references
  *Statement of purpose
  *An up-to-date resume
  *Official transcripts
  *

  Our next start is August 29, 2022
```

I need to remove last "*" character from this String

Answer (score 1):

```
x.substringBeforeLast('*') + x.substringAfterLast('*');
```

should work well.

https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/atlas.en-us.apexref.meta/apexref/apex_methods_system_string.htm